# Are $\Bbb Q[x]/<x^2-1>$ and $\Bbb Q[x]$ isomorphic to any subring of $\Bbb R$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Are $\Bbb Q[x]/<x^2-1>$ and $\Bbb Q[x]$ isomorphic to any subring of $\Bbb R$?

We know that $x^2-1$ is not irreducible so the quotient ring $\Bbb Q[x]/<x^2-1>$ is not a field. But I am wondering whether it is possible to identify that by some subring of $\Bbb R.$ What is confusing about this is that we are like adjoining a square root of $1$ but we know that the square root of $1$ already exists in the field of 
$\Bbb Q.$ Also, how about $\Bbb Q[x]$? Is $\Bbb R$ an extension of $\Bbb Q[x]?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $\Bbb Q[x] \cong \Bbb Q[\pi]$ (since $\pi$ is transcendental) and $\Bbb Q[\pi]$ is a subring of $\Bbb R$. So $\Bbb Q[x]$ is isomorphic to a subring of $\Bbb R$.

As for $\Bbb Q[x] / (x^2 - 1)$. Since $\Bbb R$ is zero divisor free, any subring of $\Bbb R$ will also be zero divisor free. But $\Bbb Q[x] / (x^2 - 1)$ isn't (since $(x-1)(x+1) = 0$), so is can't be isomorphic to any subring of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks so much. May I ask why $\Bbb Q[x]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[\pi]?$

Comment: @ButterMath It comes down to the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental. Define the homomorphism $\varphi: \Bbb Q[x] \to \Bbb R$ such that $\varphi(x) = \pi$. Since $\pi$ is transcendental, $\text{Ker}(\varphi) = \{ 0 \}$. (This is because the only polynomial $p \in \Bbb Q[x]$ that could get mapped to $0$ would have to have $\pi$ as a root. But $\pi$ is transcendental.) Thus $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: @ButterMath And for surjectivity, you just have to show that the image of $\varphi$ is $\Bbb Q[\pi]$. This is straightforward.

Comment: @Buttermath: note that aras chose $\pi$ because it's famous, not because of any special property besides "is transcendental". If you don't know how to prove that $\pi$ is transcendental (which is the case of most people), then you can be satisfied by saying "there exist transcendental numbers [see Liouville or Cantor. Cantor's proof is simpler]. Let $a$ be any of them, then $\mathbb{Q}[x] \simeq \mathbb{Q}[a] \subset \mathbb{R}$"

Comment: @aras Sorry. It just occurred to me that why it is the case that the image of your homomorphism is $\Bbb Q[\pi]$?

Comment: @Y.X. Every polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, when you input $x=\pi$ (i.e. transform it with $\varphi$), returns a linear combination of powers of $\pi$. So it's in $\Bbb Q[\pi]$.